# Who selects Pence's Replacement in Indiana?

Tags: united-states, election, government

With Pence being selected as Trump's VP, the 22 members of the Indiana Republican Party Central Committee now meet and decide his replacement for the Republican candidate in the Gubernatorial election.  How are members for that committee selected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The twenty-two members are listed [here](http://indiana.gop/counties) (ignore the two national committee members at the end).  Jeff Cardwell was elected state chair via a [staged election](http://indiana.gop/news/jeff-cardwell-elected-indiana-republican-party-chairman).  Note that the eighteen district members are called chairs and vice-chairs.

[Dubois county](http://www.duboisgop.org/?page_id=75) describes how the system works there.  Presumably the other counties work similarly.  In Dubois, there are twelve townships with forty precincts.  Each precinct elects a committee member who then appoints a vice-chair of the opposite gender.  So eighty voters total in that county.  They then select a county chair and vice-chair.  All the county chairs and vice-chairs together elect a statewide chair, vice-chair, treasurer, and secretary who are the first four members of the statewide committee.

The district chairs and vice-chairs are selected by the county chairs and vice-chairs in the district.  Note that a county can be all in one district or spread across multiple districts.